# Shipout and writes to file

Tags: dvi, shipout

During compilation of a latex document, the pages are "shipped out" one at a time. I understand this is marked by console message [1], [2], [3] etc, making each page. However, by inspecting writes to the DVI file, I have established that the DVI file is not actually written at the time of these [n] messages being printed. Rather it seems that data is cached and only hits disk at some later point. For small documents it seems that all pages are written in one go at the end of the compile process.

To investigate this I have intercepted the fwrite call. It is not called on every shipout.

My question is: is there a way to force latex to write to the DVI file on every shipout, that is, when it finishes compiling each page of content. This is to enable some custom dvi preview functionality that I want to implement.

Comment: Which implementation of TeX are you using? TeX Live on Linux? And which binary (pdfTeX I guess, as LaTeX no longer works with tex?)

Comment: I'm using TeX Live on Debian. I'm using the "latex" binary.

Comment: latex is a symlink to pdftex for buffer size handling see for example https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source/blob/765915a9ac285d8a17f0ea83b7f75addee2c73f0/texk/web2c/tex.ch#L2614 (my initial comment was wrong as you observed sorry:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you guessed, output to the DVI file is buffered, and written out half of `dvi_buf_size` at a time.

In the original Knuth TeX, see [§594](https://mirrors.ctan.org/info/knuth-pdf/tex/tex.pdf#page=220):

> The DVI bytes are output to a buffer instead of being written directly to the output file. This makes it possible to reduce the overhead of subroutine calls, thereby measurably speeding up the computation, since output of DVI bytes is part of TeX’s inner loop.

See also §597–598 which go into details of the implementation:

- Bytes are written into the buffer with `dvi_out`
- When the unflushed part of the buffer reaches half the size of `dvi_buf`, the procedure `write_dvi` is called, which does the actual writing into the file.

In PdfTeX the same implementation is kept ([§624–625](https://mirrors.ctan.org/info/knuth-pdf/pdftex/pdftex.pdf#page=258)). In practice, in web2c, the procedure `write_dvi` is [changed](https://mirrors.ctan.org/info/knuth-pdf/pdftex/pdftex-changes.pdf#page=105) to [be](https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source/blob/765915a9ac285d8a17f0ea83b7f75addee2c73f0/texk/web2c/texmfmp.h#L86) a [call](https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source/blob/765915a9ac285d8a17f0ea83b7f75addee2c73f0/texk/web2c/cpascal.h#L147-L152) to `fwrite`.

If you don't care about speed (on which this will likely have only a tiny effect anyway: for most LaTeX documents, most of the time is spent expanding macros rather than writing to the output file), you could try changing the implementation of TeX and re-compiling: either changing the `dvi_buf_size` to be really small (a comment says it needs to be a multiple of 8, so maybe 8 will work?), or redefine `dvi_out` (which is intended to write one byte to the DVI buffer) to write out the byte to the file directly with `fwrite`. Will be curious to know if it works!

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to know, very nice idea about redefining dvi_buf_size to equal 8. Are constants like this compiled in, or adjustable in the config file, do you know?

Comment: @JamieVicary I see some examples in the TeX Live repo of setting `dvi_buf_size = 800` in `texmf.cnf`, so maybe it is adjustable… haven't tried it myself

Comment: @JamieVicary the default texmf.cnf in texmf-dist/web2c has comments for every parameter that can be set by the config file (which includes this)

Comment: @JamieVicary I just tried it and unfortunately setting `dvi_buf_size` doesn't seem to achieve the intended effect. On my system by default it seems to write out 4096 bytes at a time (if I'm interpreting the output of strace correctly), and if I *increase* it really high I can get it to write out alternately 4096 and 28672 bytes (adding up to 32768), but I wasn't able to get it to go lower (or higher than that limit). So you may have to fiddle with the source code.

Answer (score 1):

I have a guess this may be to do with the constant "dvi_buf_size", which is set to 16384 in some distributions (I'm not sure about mine.) So I wonder if \shipout will only trigger a write to file if the page size exhausts this buffer (or half of it.) And in fact, in my tests I'm seeing dvi file writes of 8192, which is indeed half of 16384.

So my theory is that \shipout doesn't write to the DVI file, it just sends the data to the DVI buffer, which is written to file every 8192 bytes. The actual page structure of the document is irrelevant. If the \shipout doesn't cause the buffer to reach 8192 bytes, it won't trigger a write to file, and if the \shipout delivers more than 8192 bytes, I speculate this will cause writes to file until the buffer is less than 8192 bytes. In any case, the writes to file are not page-by-page.